# Camera video not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, browser, camera, cross-browser

I'm attempting to access the camera of a current user device and display the camera's video before they can take a picture. It works perfectly on Android and browsers, but not on iPhones for some strange reason. Even when the screen is black, I can still capture a picture. It's just a dark video camera.

Snippet of the code

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .enumerateDevices()
      .then(function (devices) {
        devices.forEach(function (device) {
          if (device.kind == "videoinput") {
            let temp = videoInputs;
            temp.push(
              device.kind + ": " + device.label + " id = " + device.deviceId
            );
            setVideoInputs(temp);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      });
  }, []);


  const getVideo = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: {
          // width: 1920,
          // height: 1080,
          facingMode: orientation ? "environment" : "user",
        },
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        console.log(stream);
        setError("");
        setVideoStream(stream);
        let video = videoRef.current;
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.toString())
        // setError("Permission denied. Turn on your camera to continue");
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getVideo();
    return () => {
      stopVideo();
    };
  }, [orientation]);
```

Comment: Do you get the permission prompt when your camera stays black?

Comment: Yes. I enable it every time but then the screen goes dark